# is there any way to run React + Django in same project without running npm run build again and again?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have enough knowledge about Django and recently learned react and i like to combine both.

I have gone through a couple of video tutorials and i am successful in integrating them.

but the problem is i should either build a rest API and a react app in two different projects and them combine them or i need to run `npm run build` every time i make any changes on my front end.

so if anybody have an alternative for this(Running React on Django server continuously without running `build` again and again) please tell me.

Comment: If you used create-react-app for the front end, then no. Code is live. You ONLY run npm build when you are ready to "deploy", say, to heroku or netlify or one of the app hosts.

Comment: You can use django-webpack-loader, but you will have to modify/override the create-react-app webpack config. I only recommend it if you are fairly familiar with how webpack works and can be configured.
https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json file there will  be script tag as below,

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack  --mode development ./src/index.js --output ./static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./src/index.js --output ./static/frontend/main.js"
  },
```

add `--watch` tag with dev script as below,

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --watch --mode development ./src/index.js --output ./static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./src/index.js --output ./static/frontend/main.js"
  },
```

Then do `npm run dev`

So the JS will run without breaking.Even if you change the files inside React, it will update and run automatically.

The file structure may vary according to your project but logic is same

Answer (score 0):

**I have just Found a simplest way to keep using django apis while working with react**

step 1 -> just npm run your react project inside your react directory using

```
npm run start
```

you will see the development server starts at Local:            at http://localhost:3000 by default

---

step 2 -> move to your **django project directory** and start your django server **in another terminal**

```
python manage.py runserver
```

this will start your django at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ by default

---

now whereever you are using axios or other bundles to fetch apis from django at the same port just add http://127.0.0.1:8000/ to the starting of their url

**you may now see an error that says cors header is not allowed from 3000 port but don't worry just few more steps **

step 3 -> go to your django directory and write

```
pip install django-cors-header
```

step 4 -> now go the setting files of the django project and make following changes as below :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'corsheaders',
...
]
MIDDLEWARE=[
...
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
...
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
'http://localhost:3000',
]
```

for thanks mark this answer useful!  and for any query comment