# Update changes on React + Django without running "npm run build" everytime

Tags: reactjs, django, django-react

My Django + React app is integrated fine at least for most parts. Because every time I have to make changes on my React code, in order to apply those changes I have to stop django from running then run npm run build everytime.

I've already read this [is there any way to run React + Django in same project without running npm run build again and again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577449/is-there-any-way-to-run-react-django-in-same-project-without-running-npm-run-b) and tried to apply it to my problem but it didn't work.

Still new in React but with a few experiences with Django. Would appreciate your help

Comment: I guess this answer may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577449/is-there-any-way-to-run-react-django-in-same-project-without-running-npm-run-b

Comment: Django+React tutorial https://saasitive.com/django-react/boilerplate/ - the frontend and backend code are separated there

Answer (score 0):

When developing with Django and react I have often found it easier to import libraries (the minified versions usually) through script tags in the html that is served to the front end, this entirely circumvents the need to have npm in use entirely. If you do switch to this method, simply make sure that debug is set to true and you will be able to start the server by running 'python manage.py runserver' and you'll be able to access everything on the Django port that you are using.